# No saved view state could be found for the view identifier, still no valid solution

Tags: jsf

I do realize that there are several topics like this here, however I couldn't find anything there that would help me.

I get this exception randomly at clicking buttons. Yet the next time I click the same button in a second it works just fine.

**Apache Log**

```
Dec 09, 2015 12:05:39 PM org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler logException
SEVERE: FullAjaxExceptionHandler: An exception occurred during processing JSF ajax request. Error page '/loginViewExpired.xhtml' will be shown.
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: /login.xhtmlNo saved view state could be found for the view identifier: /login.xhtml
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:171)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:170)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:44)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at ru.nspk.system.server.jsf.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:55)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>        
    </listener>  
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
        <param-value>ALL</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
        <param-value>ALL</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.resourceOptimization.enabled</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            60
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ru.nspk.system.server.HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloWorldServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/loginError.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/loginViewExpired.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/loginError.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <ejb-local-ref>
        <ejb-ref-name>PlatformCertificationLogManagement</ejb-ref-name>
        <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
        <local-home/>
        <local>ru.nspk.system.server.ejb.session.LogManagementLocal</local>
        <ejb-link>PlatformCertificationLogManagementBean</ejb-link>
    </ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-local-ref>
        <ejb-ref-name>PlatformCertificationUserManagement</ejb-ref-name>
        <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
        <local-home/>
        <local>ru.nspk.system.server.ejb.session.UserManagementLocal</local>
        <ejb-link>PlatformCertificationUserManagementBean</ejb-link>
    </ejb-local-ref>
</web-app>
```

I tried adding to my Web.xml:

```
<context-param>
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

then:

```
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
<param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Then I made sure all of my beans were serializable. And yet I still receive the same random mistake every now and then.

Comment: @BalusC I already stated why this question is different and why I created a duplicate topic.

Comment: @BalusC On the contrary, when it comes to JSF and Apache there is not enough logic, but enough magic to call it a random problem. That's not only my opinion. I shared everything I think could be of use, if something else is needed, I would be happy to provide.